# How do I resize a wordpress featured image to be 620 width by whatever corresponding height in the loop but not permanently?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, image-scaling

Here is the website I am attempting this on: http://increaseinwebtraffic.com/marywood/deals/

The top few deals are larger than 620 width, but the bottom ones are smaller. I tried to use the code below with no success. I've Googled around and only found permanent solutions.

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( array(620,295) ); ?>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should move this question to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com. You're likely to get awesome answers there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following code.

```
<?php
$thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID());
if (!empty($thumbnail_id))
{
  $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumbnail_id, 'full');
  if (count ($thumbnail) >= 3)
  {
    $thumbnail_url = $thumbnail[0];
    $thumbnail_width = $thumbnail[1];
    $thumbnail_height = $thumbnail[2];

    $thumbnail_w = 620;
    $thumbnail_h = floor($thumbnail_height * $thumbnail_w / $thumbnail_width);
  }
}

if (!empty ($thumbnail_url)): ?>
  <img class="thumbnail" src="<?php echo $thumbnail_url; ?>" alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"
       width="<?php echo $thumbnail_w; ?>" height="<?php echo $thumbnail_h; ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

http://www.boxoft.net/2011/10/display-the-wordpress-featured-image-without-stretching-it/

Answer (score 0):

What about putting a  around that an setting the above code and then using CSS to set the width and height? Something like this:

**CSS**

```
.deals img {
 width: 620px;
 max-height: 295px;
}
```

**HTML / PHP**

```
<div class="deals"><?php the_post_thumbnail( array(620,295) ); ?></div>
```

Comment: I've tried this but this stretches the picture out if its width is lower, and if its height is lower is stays the same. How can I stretch the picture proportionally to have a width of 620px? I don't mind if the picture is cut off because the div it is within makes overflow invisible.

Comment: try removing the height and adding overflow: hidden;

of course your containing div will have to have a height set to it in order for the overflow:hidden; to work on your img

Comment: Problem is, the_post_thumbnail by default adds height and width, right?

Comment: personally, i'd remove it from the php and let css do all the work. i'm not sure if there's a benefit to one way or the other.

the other option is to just crop and resize all your images to the right proportions so you don't have to rely on server/browser side scripting/styling to do the work